# What is the equivalent of the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK for the .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: msbuild, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

On our build server, we've installed the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK in order to kick off MSBuild and run our builds. Now we are upgrading to the .NET Framework 3.5. We do not want to install the complete Visual Studio, but we cannot find a .NET Framework 3.5 SDK on the internet either?

The question: What do we need ot download and install to get the equivalent of a .NET Framework 3.5 SDK installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF)

Actually, you only need the SDK for a few things (the RDL reports compiler `.targets` file leaps to mind, since that one has bitten me recently). The framework itself can do most things.

Answer (score 4):

.net 3.5 comes with compiler and msbuild bundled with it. just download the normal .net 3.5 framework (not the client profile) and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Is [this what](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en) you're looking for?

Edit: +1 Joachim's answer. Didn't know MSBuild was part of the SDK.